# url-natbib-apastyle

Tags: errors, apacite, url

I am sorry if this has been asked but I cannot find an answer. I am using a template and it uses apastyle citations. However, when I have an url (citing a data source) the code breaks down. 
Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)





\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}





%%% bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{natbib}
%\bibpunct[: ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{, }

\usepackage{authblk}

%\usepackage{tgbonum}


\title{TITLE}

\begin{document}


The \textit{Real GDP Growth} measures the growth of real GDP, percent change from previous year \citep{oecdgrowth}.
\section*{Notes}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=!,labelindent=-15pt,itemindent=0pt]
    \item 
\end{enumerate}

\singlespacing 

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{jobname.bib}
```

\end{document}

```
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @misc{oecdgrowth,
author = {OECD},
year={2014},
title = {Economic Outlook No. 96 (Edition 2014/2)},
howpublished= {\url{https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/economics/data/oecd-economic-outlook-statistics-and-projections/oecd-economic-outlook-no-96_data-00717-en}},
note = {Accessed: 25 March 2016},
} }
\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose. You could make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions and observations:

- Don't load both the `apacite` package and the `natbib` package -- they're not mutually compatible. Since you're using the `apacite` bibliography style, you should load the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` (and not load `natbib` separately) if you want to be able to use the commands `\citet` and `\citep`.
- Change `\bibliography{jobname.bib}` to `\bibliography{\jobname}` (unless the name of your main tex file really is `jobname.tex`, in which case the bib file's name will be `jobname.bib`).
- In the bib entry, enclose the contents of the `title` field in an extra pair of curly braces to prevent the words from being lowercased.
- Still in the bib entry, change the `howpublished` field name to `url`, and omit the `\url{...}` "wrapper".
- I would also like to suggest that you load the `xurl` package; compared with the `url` package, its extra (and very handy!) capability is that it allows line breaks in long URL strings at arbitrary points.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%% no need to load 'filecontents' package unless your TeX distribution isn't up to date
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{oecdgrowth,
  author = {OECD},
  year   ={2014},
  title  = {{Economic Outlook No.\ 96 (Edition 2014/2)}},
  url    = {https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/economics/data/oecd-economic-outlook-statistics-and-projections/oecd-economic-outlook-no-96_data-00717-en},
  note   = {Accessed: 25 March 2016},
} 
\end{filecontents} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage{xurl}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}
\citep{oecdgrowth}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

***Addendum***: As you may be aware, the `apacite` package and bibliography style implement the formatting requirements of the 6th edition of the APA manual. Importantly, the 6th edition is no longer the most recent edition. If you need to format the bibliography according to the current, i.e., **7th edition**, you will need to switch from the `apacite` package and BibTeX to the `biblatex` package and `biber`. (I'm not aware of plans to update the `apacite` package to implement the formatting requirements of the 7th edition.) If you make this switch, you should also change the field name `note` to `urldate` and change its contents to ISO format; in short, change `note = {Accessed: 25 March 2016}` to `urldate= {2016-03-25}`.

The following code and associated screenshot show how this might be done with minimal amount of fuss. After making the changes, do make sure to run biber, not BibTeX, to create the formatted bibliography file.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{oecdgrowth,
  author = {OECD},
  year   = {2014},
  title  = {{Economic Outlook No.\ 96 (Edition 2014/2)}},
  url    = {https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/economics/data/oecd-economic-outlook-statistics-and-projections/oecd-economic-outlook-no-96_data-00717-en},
  urldate= {2016-03-25},
} 
\end{filecontents} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xurl}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}
\citep{oecdgrowth}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```